# apply_assync() executes lines outside the function

Tags: python

I have a code:

```
            import multiprocessing as mp
            import time

            sym=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
            print "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
            def test(c):
                print c
            gjd=0
            if __name__ == '__main__':
                    if float(gjd)<((time.time()/60)):
                        gjd=float(int(time.time() / 60) + 1)
                        zxc=time.time()
                        p = mp.Pool(processes=7)
                        for t in sym:
                            p.apply_async(test, args=(t,))
                        time.sleep(0.6)
                        p.close()
                        p.join()
                        print '----------------------------',time.time()-zxc,'----------------------------'
```

However, I do not truly understand why the line

```
        print "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
```

was executed 7 times prior to the amount of worker defined at

```
                    p = mp.Pool(processes=7)
```

The output of my code is:

```
            AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
            AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
            AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
            AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
            AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
            1
            2
            3
            4
            5
            6
            7
            8
            9
            10
            AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
            AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
            A
            ---------------------------- 0.858999967575 ----------------------------

            Process finished with exit code 0
```

How can I prevent the executions of lines outside of the function called at my multiprocessing pool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`multiprocessing` imports the module, hence why every stray (=outside of a function, class or `if __name__ == '__main__'`) code will execute.

To solve this, simply move everything to a function or to inside the `if __name__ == '__main__'`.

See *Safe importing of main module* on the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods):

> Safe importing of main module
>
> Make sure that the main module can be safely imported by a new Python
>   interpreter without causing unintended side effects (such a starting a
>   new process).

Comment: So I should also put the import statements inside the if __name__ == 'main' except for the import multiprocessing?

Comment: @MichaelEsporlas The imports can stay